# displaying only the current user data

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I protected data_service with current user to only display the current user's habits.
data_service.dart:

```
class DataService {...
  late final Database db;
  Users? _user;
  late final StreamData<Map<int, Habit>> habits;
  

  Future<void> init() async {
    db = await HabitsDb.connectToDb();
    habits = StreamData(initialValue: await _getAllHabits(), broadcast: true);
 }

  String get userEmail => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.email;

  Future<Map<int, Habit>> _getAllHabits() async {
    getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail); //issue 
    final habits = await _getAllHabitsFromDb();
    final map = Map<int, Habit>();
    final currentUser = _user;
    print(currentUser);
    for (final habit in habits) {
      if (currentUser != null) {
        print(currentUser.id);
        print(habit.userId);
        if (habit.userId == currentUser.id) {
          map[habit.id] = habit;
        }
      }
      //map[habit.userId] = currentUser?.id;
    }
    return map;
  }

  Future<List<Habit>> _getAllHabitsFromDb() async {
    final habitsMap = await HabitsDb.getAllHabits(db);
    final habitsList = habitsMap.map((e) => Habit.fromDb(e)).toList();
    return habitsList;
  }

Future<Users> getOrCreateUser({
    required String email,
    bool setAsCurrentUser = true,
  }) async {
    try {
      //we found the user
      final user = await getUser(email: email);
      if (setAsCurrentUser) {
        _user = user;
      }
      print(_user?.email);
      return user;
    } on CouldNotFindUser {
      //we didn't find the user
      final createdUser = await createUser(email: email);
      if (setAsCurrentUser) {
        _user = createdUser;
      }
      return createdUser;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
...}
```

in main class:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  final dataService = DataService();
  await dataService.init();
  GetIt.I.registerSingleton(dataService);
... }
```

StreamData class:

```
class StreamData<T> {
  List<Habit> _notes = [];

  User? _user;

  late final StreamController<T> _controller;
  Stream<T> get stream => _controller.stream;

  late T _value;
  T get value => _value;

  StreamData({required T initialValue, bool broadcast = true}) {
    if (broadcast) {
      _controller = StreamController<T>.broadcast();
    } else {
      _controller = StreamController<T>();
    }
    _value = initialValue;
  }
```

the problem is that the line getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail); is only called once and it does not work when I switch user and I need to Hot Restart to fix it. I think using Futurebuilder will  fix it. but if yes, how do I use it when there is a need to call dataService.init at the beginning of the main?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `getOrCreateUser` function is declared as `async`, you'll want to use `await` when you call it in `_getAllHabits`:

```
await getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail)
```

This ensures the `getOrCreateUser` code has completed before the rest of the code in `_getAllHabits` (that depends on the result of `getOrCreateUser`) executes.